# How to increase the background task time in sleep mode in iOS

Tags: ios, background

I am using iOS 7 and I can able to continue my task for 3 minutes when my device moves to sleep mode. But I need to increase this time without using services like voIP,audio or GPS..Need help..

Comment: Don't think it is possible without getting your app rejected.

Comment: You only have 3 minutes of background execution time for a long-running task. You need to re-think how your app works.

Comment: If i don't want the services in my app, what can I do? There is any other ways?

Comment: Thanks for your responses @Paulw11

Comment: And also thanks to @humblePilgrim